# How to create a array with identifiers

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I want to create an array with identifiers
To be more clear

```
Jack  Karen Tom Example Person
30    40    50  Age
```

Like this
It does not be array necessarily but ı must search the age with name
Using database is not fine for me, the age and name is just the simplification of my problem
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Comment: Perhaps a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Create a class `Person` and add instances of it in a collection like a `List<Person>`. You can find a person for exampe with LINQ: `Person jack = allPersons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Jack");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple implementation could use a Dictionary like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> values = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            { "Jack", 30 },
            { "Karen", 40 },
            { "Tom", 50 },
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine(values["Jack"]);
    }
}
```

If you want to store more complex values, you can use a C# class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

You can then create instances of this class and use them:

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Jack", Age = 30 };
```